# Push Bluetooth pairing request Dialogue to Front

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have an APP that connect to Bluetooth and requires a pin to complete the connection. everything works fine except for one issue. When the Pairing request box is to appear it seems the be in the background of the APP. I observed this by the APP stops to respond to user input and after the pairing request box times out i see a flash of the request box and it disappears. Also pressing the back button seems to cancel the request as i see the flash of the request box before it disappears. is there anyway i can force the pairing request box to appear in the foreground every time?

I confirmed that I am able to type into the box, however, the box is not shown on screen